# How to retrieve specific tag from an xml file in spring batch in java

Tags: xml-parsing, spring-batch

This is what I need to implement. I need to create a batch which:
1. READ: will read mutiple xml files from a folder
2. PROCESS: extract the values of some tags from one of these xmls (as explained below)and save the extracted data in a DB.
3. WRITE: move the processed xml file as it is to another directory.

There are no repeating tags in the xml.

For example if this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
<info>
    <ssn>5214365214356</ssn>
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>12</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</info>
<address>
    <street>abc</street>
    <city>atrdtysaf</city>
    <state>abcsvc</state>
    <country>USA</country>
</address>
<healthinfo>
    <smoking>no</smoking>
    <drinking>no</drinking>
</healthinfo>
</report>
```

I want to extract the values of "ssn, gender and country tags only". Please note that the actual xml would be relatively huge. I am supposed to use StaxEvenItemReader provided by  spring batch.

Comment: please state your question clearly and explicitly.. so that others might have more chance to help you..

Comment: Do you mean you need to extract the value from a single tag within an entire XML file or only one tag within a given XML block that repeats within the file?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract the value from a single tag within the entire xml which has no repeating tags. I have edited the question accordingly, i hope m clear this time :)

Comment: I could acheive this by using jaxb annotations..